# Assign different tasks to different celery workers

Tags: python, celery

I am running my server using this command:

```
celery worker -Q q1,q2 -c 2
```

which shows that my server will handle all the tasks on queues `q1` and `q2`, and I have 2 workers running. My server should support 2 different tasks:

```
@celery.task(name='test1')
def test1():
    print "test1"
    time.sleep(3)

@celery.task(name='test2')
def test2():
    print "test2"
```

If I send my `test1` tasks to queue `q1` and `test2` to `q2`, both workers will run both tasks. So the result will be:

```
test1
test2
test1
test2
...
```

Now what I need is one of my workers handle `test1` and the other one handles `test2`. One solution is to run two celery workers like this:

```
celery worker -Q q1 -c 1
celery worker -Q q2 -c 1
```

And each one handles 1 queue. But I would like to have them cleaner and use `-c 2`. I found [Celery Routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) but am not sure if that is what I want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer and I am putting it here in case someone else wanted to do the same:

Instead of using `celery worker -Q q1,q2 -c 2`, `celery multi` could be used:

```
celery multi start 2 -Q:1 q1 -Q:2 q2 -c:1 1 -c:2 1
```

Which says that we have 2 queues: `-Q:1 q1` means queue #1 with name of `q1` and same for `q2` and we have different concurrencies for each queue, `-c:1 1` means the first celery worker has a concurrency of 1.

Comment: So you're using two brokers here? I wonder if it's possible to just use a shared broker and a shared worker server? The worker just call test1() or test2() according to task names. Thanks.

Comment: That is actually what you want. Shared broker and server. They are just different workers, handling different tasks using different queues.

Comment: Can you point me to the doc where I can learn how to dispatch tasks to the corresponding queues? Because from the above code, I don't see any binding relationship between test1, test2 and q1, q2. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JFreebird you can find bunch of examples here: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html

Comment: the same configure for each work can just write once: `celery multi start 2  -c 1 -Q:1 q1 -Q:2 q2 `  <= more butti...